# Show that $d \mu:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} d \mu_{k} \wedge d x^{k}$ is independent of the coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

suppose that $M$ is a n-dimensional manifold, $\mu \in A^{1}(M)$, in any chart, let $\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu_{k} d x^{k}$, show that $d \mu:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} d \mu_{k} \wedge d x^{k}$ is independent of coordinate, here is my attempt, I want to express the $\mu$ with respect to other basis and recalculate the differential but I don't know what to do next

Comment: This form is called the Liouville form, or tautological $1-$form. To show that $d\mu$ is independent, it is enough to prove that $\mu$ is. This is quite easy, and  explained in any book about symplectic geometry

Comment: @Thomas I don't think this is related to the Liouville form: it is just the decomposition of $\mu$ in the basis $\{dx^k\}$ and its exterior differential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p \in M$ and let $\left\{x^{1}, x^{2}, \ldots, x^{n}\right\}$ and $\left\{y^{1}, y^{2}, \ldots, y^{n}\right\}$ be two coordinates around $p \in M$ $\quad \mu=\sum_{\text {Let }}^{n} \mu_{k} d x^{k} \quad \mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \tilde{\mu}_{j} d y^{j}$ respectively in the coordinate systems $\left\{x^{1}, x^{2}, \ldots, x^{n}\right\}$ and $\left\{y^{1}, y^{2}, \ldots, y^{n}\right\}$ and Then we have by the change of basis formula for a one-form
$$
\tilde{\mu}_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}
$$
Hence we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
d \widetilde{\mu}_{j} &=d\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d\left(\mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} d\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^{k}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right) d y^{k}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{k} y^{j}} d y^{k}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence,
$d \mu=d\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} \tilde{\mu}_{j} d y^{j}\right)$
$=\sum_{j=1}^{n} d\left(\tilde{\mu}_{j} d y^{j}\right)$
$=\sum_{j=1}^{n} d \tilde{\mu}_{j} \wedge d y^{j}$
$=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{k} y^{j}} d y^{k}\right)\right) \wedge d y^{j}$
$=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\left(d \mu_{i} \wedge d y^{j}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu_{i} \frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{k} y^{j}}\left(d y^{k} \wedge d y^{j}\right)$
$=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \wedge\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}} d y^{j}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{k} y^{j}} d y^{k} \wedge d y^{j}\right)$
$=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \wedge d x^{i}$
$\left(\begin{array}{l}\text { as } d y^{j} \wedge d y^{k}=0 \text { for all } j=k \\ \text { and for each pair } 1 \leq j, k \leq n\end{array}\right.$
such that $j \neq k$ we have
$\frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{k} y^{j}}=\frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{j} y^{k}}$
$\left.\begin{array}{c}\text { and } \\ d y^{k} \wedge d y^{j}=-d y^{j} \wedge d y^{k} \\ \frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{k} y^{j}} d y^{k} \wedge d y^{j}=-\frac{\partial^{2} x^{i}}{\partial y^{j} y^{k}} d y^{j} \wedge d y^{k}\end{array}\right)$
Hence the expression is independent of the coordinate i.e.
$$
d \mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n} d \tilde{\mu}_{j} \wedge d y^{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d \mu_{i} \wedge d x^{i}
$$